# Export csv from google drive API

Tags: javascript, csv, google-api, google-drive-api

I'm using googles drive API to download files of spreadsheet type. This works just fine except for when I try to download it in text/csv.

Is should be supported according to this page:
https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads

So this code works fine:

```js
var request = gapi.client.drive.files.export({
  'fileId': fileId,
  'mimeType': 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
})
request.then(function(response) {
  console.log(response);
}, function(err) {
  console.log('Error');
  console.log(err.result.error);
});
```

This code doesn't:

```js
var request = gapi.client.drive.files.export({
  'fileId': fileId,
  'mimeType': 'text/csv'
})
request.then(function(response) {
  console.log(response);
}, function(err) {
  console.log('Error');
  console.log(err.result.error);
});
```

The error I get from the server is:

- domain: "global"
- message: "Internal Error"
- reason: "internalError"

Does anyone know what could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with the Drive API v3, and it has been raised with the engineering team. Please follow [this issue](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4253) for updates.